# Can a huge DataStructure be given directly to MapReduce to process without loading onto HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, apache-spark, hadoop-streaming

We are investigating the idea of Streaming a huge N-Dimensional Datastructure (NetCDF file) as input to the Mapper function without having to write to a textfile and then Loading onto HDFS.  We have an application which is already holding this huge DataStructure. So we want to skip all the overhead involved in writing and reading from textfiles. 
We need some input to the below questions..

1) Can a third party application stream data directly to MapReduce?

2) If the above is possible, Will MapReduce handle splitting this DataStructure into Input Chunks or do we need to explicitly do this?

3) Is this possible to implement on Apache SPARK as Spark operates from DRAM and DataStructure is also on DRAM so we don't have to move data between different applications. (I haven't explored Spark yet, sorry if this is a dumb thought..!! )

Any pointers in this direction is greatly appreciated..!

Similar ideas:
https://www.mapr.com/developercentral/code/immediate-mapreduce-continuously-ingested-data#.VAXez_ldVQF

http://d2i.indiana.edu/sites/default/files/escience13_jiaan.pdf

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes as long as you can create an [`InputFormat`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) for it you can use it as input to a Mapreduce job.
2) Yes you have to handle it on your own, but there is good news, many streaming technologies already have implemented the input formats for you, a good one that I am familiar with is Kafka, the are a million implementations of `KafkaInputFormat` floating around I think linkedin's [camus](https://github.com/linkedin/camus/blob/55b99186ec1e55354ceb0ce6b48a2c6784c12108/camus-etl-kafka/src/main/java/com/linkedin/camus/etl/kafka/mapred/EtlInputFormat.java) has one that works though it might be overkill, it seems more complex than some of the others out there.
3) More good news spark comes with a streaming connector to Kafka (and could also probably use the one that Hadoop uses through [`newApiHadoopFile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext))

Comment: Id add that Spark will prob require the least amount of code and effort to get something working, and has the most flexibility.

Comment: @samthebest isn't that true by default, theoretically there is really very little spark doesn't do better than Hadoop Mapreduce

Comment: @aaronman : Thank you for your response. Kafka seems interesting. I am working on the same idea and i will post if i find anything interesting. Do you think we could write any customInputFormat like FileInputFormat to split this datastructure from 3rd party application?

Comment: @Naveen not following the last question

Comment: @aaronman: sorry for my english..! i see that kafkaInputFormat may fit for my case. I have also looked at camus's inputformat and yeah it looks complicated in the first look. i will try them.. Thank you for your valuable input.